# how this statement should be represented in MIPS32 assembly

Tags: assembly, mips32

it doesnt seem right to me the way it is. i know that a[i-j] is get the index of whatever value i-j is. So if i was 5 and j 3, you would store the value of a[2] into b[8]. What it looks like im doing in MIPS is taking the value of a[i] and subtracting a[j] and then storing that value in b[8]. any idea how it can be improved?

high level lang statement

```
b[8]=a[i-j]
```

assembly

```
lw $t0, 4i($t1)
lw $t2, 4j($t1)
sub $t3, $t0, $t2
sw $t3, 32($t4)
```

Comment: Does that even assemble? `lw $t0, 4i($t1)` certainly doesn't look like valid MIPS assembly.

Comment: Can you help me how can i improve it?